# Rails Active Record Association Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following models which looks like:

user.rb

```
has_many: groups
```

group.rb

```
has_many: channels
```

I want a query that returns a list of the "name" fields for all the channels belong to all the groups belonging to User.

What I have below doesn't work, any guidance appreciated.

```
Group.all.where("user_id = ?", 1).joins(:channels)
```

Comment: why it doesn't work? do you get any errors?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  When I type this in the View:

'code'
     <% @user_groups.each do |group| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= group.name %></td>
      <td><%= group.channels.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>


I get the Group name field correctly but the channel field I get the word Channel - i.e. the name of the field rather than the value in it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

1. Channel `belongs_to` Group
2. You have a `@user`

I believe you should be able to do:

```
Channel.where(group: @user.groups).pluck(:name)
```

Which should return an `array` (which I assume is what you mean by `list`) of the `name` attribute of all `Channel`s belonging to all `Group`s which belong to `@user`.

In your case (indicated in your comment to your original post which really should have been an edit), you should do:

```
<% @user_groups.each do |group| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= group.name %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= group.channels.pluck(:name) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```